# C++でのRのsample()

Tags: c++

Rには、ベクタ`x`のそれぞれに確率を割り振る`sample()`という関数があると思うのですが (`sample(x, size, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL)`)、同じことをC++ですることは (ライブラリを使うなどすれば)可能でしょうか。
Eigenライブラリでは、すべての要素に均一の確率しか割り振れないようでしたが、工夫すればできるのでしょうか。

Comment: C++ ではなく Python ですが、[Weighted random generation in Python](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/01/22/weighted-random-generation-in-python) が参考になるかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

ライブラリは探せばあると思いますが、自分で実装したほうが探すより早いかな。
sample()の挙動が正しく模擬できているかわかりませんが、以下のように実装してみました。

下記のコードはvisual studio 2015 communityで動作を確認済。

```
#include<random>
#include<vector>
#include<numeric>
#include<iostream>

//Rのsample()の挙動を模擬
template<class T>
std::vector<T> sample(const std::vector<T> & vec, const int & num_samples)
{
    // 乱数の初期値の生成器
    std::random_device rd;

    // 乱数生成器
    std::mt19937 generator(rd());

    // 一様分布の生成
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, vec.size()-1);

    // 返り値の生成
    std::vector<T> return_val(num_samples);

    // あとは結果を添えるだけ
    for (auto & elem : return_val)
    {
        elem = vec[distribution(generator)];
    }

    return(return_val);
}

//Rのsample()の挙動を模擬
template<class T>
std::vector<T> sample(const std::vector<T> & vec, const int & num_samples, const std::initializer_list<double> & list)
{
    if (vec.size() != list.size())
    {
        throw "invalid size\n";
    }

    // 乱数の初期値の生成器
    std::random_device rd;

    // 乱数生成器
    std::mt19937 generator(rd());

    // 一様分布の生成
    std::discrete_distribution<int> distribution(list);

    // 返り値の生成
    std::vector<T> return_val(num_samples);

    // あとは結果を添えるだけ
    for (auto & elem : return_val)
    {
        elem = vec[distribution(generator)];
    }

    return(return_val);
}

int main()
{
    // 動くか確認
    std::vector<int> num(5);

    std::iota(num.begin(), num.end(), 0);

    std::cout << "確率に比重がある場合:\n";

    {
        auto vec = sample(num, 10, { 0.5,2.1,3,0.4,10.0 });

        // 出力
        for (auto & elem : vec)
        {
            std::cout << elem << ", ";
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "一様な確率の場合:\n";

    {
        auto vec = sample(num, 10);

        // 出力
        for (auto & elem : vec)
        {
            std::cout << elem << ", ";
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```